# In need of a visually pleasing UML diagram tool

Tags: java, uml

I've been looking for different tools to create UML diagrams for my Java apps. My prof uses Omnigraffle, but this is only for Mac/iPad. I'm really looking for something as visually pleasing as Omni but for Linux or even Windows. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Free only or are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: I'd be willing to pay for it if its reasonably priced. Free would be best.

Comment: ...the most visually appealing UML diagrams for me were those without any visual decorations - just rectangles, ovals, arrows etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use http://argouml.tigris.org/ it's free and OK to look at :)

Answer (score 2):

or [visual paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/) they have community edition for free

Answer (score 1):

Try Sparx Enterprise Architect for Windows.  It is very reasonably priced.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the 30-day free trial

Answer (score 1):

JUDE has a community edition.  I used to think this was a terrific tool before they split it into community and paid editions.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/), I have also used Visual Paradigm community edition that @Milan mentioned before.

Comment: Don't think this is still actively developed - and win only?

Comment: Yeah it seems that it is not being developed now, too bad, but I think it is in a good state to be used for college homework, any way there are other options like Visual Paradigm community edition which is free.

Comment: There's an actively developed fork of StarUML - WhiteStarUML: https://sourceforge.net/projects/whitestaruml/

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a drawing tool (as opposed to a "modelling" tool) then take a look at [YEd](http://yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html).  Conceptually v similar to omni.  Free, works on linux/mac/osx and looks great.  Also has very nice auto-layout.

hth.

Answer (score 1):

Most minimalistic UML diagrams-editing tool (not modeling environment!) ever: [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/).
Gives reasonable black-and-white results, exports vector graphics to PDF and EPS.  Up side: A small text pane speeds up editing.  Down side: A couple of end-cases (e.g., labels on vertical lines) do not give optimal results.

Answer (score 1):

What does "visually pleasing" mean for you? I think it is a very subjective matter and should be the last thing considered when choosing a UML modeling tool.

However, I like how the [Altova UModel](http://www.altova.com/umodel.html) diagrams look, except for the use case diagrams' actor element. I'm not such a fan of *StarUML* and *Visual Paradigm*.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to try [Visio](http://visiotoolbox.com) for creating UML diagrams. Visio has the feature of dynamic, data-driven visuals which makes it one of the best software for diagramming. I use it for my diagramming needs.